# How to load a file into the database in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-file, android-fileprovider

**My scenario:** When User navigate to the file uploading page, The user can upload a maximum 5 files and before moving to the next page if the user wants to delete a uploaded file then he can delete it. The page looks similar like this, when the user uploads 4 files(IMG1, IMG2 are file names) [image]

Next once the user wish to have 4 files in the first page and move to the second page and adds the necessary personal information there and clicks submit button. The files in the first page and personal information details in second page should be loaded to the database.

**Current situation:** I know how to pass data between activities and fragments. My only concern is how to store the files in some placeholder. Now i know only to fetch the file path string but don't have any idea on how to store the file somewhere in the first page because the file will only be loaded to the database in second page.

Kindly suggest me ideas for my scenario. Million thanks!

Comment: you can store local path and pass it with intent to next page. you can easily create file object from file path

Comment: Copy the chosen files to app local cache folder(in case they are deleted), and save their file paths to database.

Comment: I'm new to android and does converting a file path to object looks like this? String dirPath = "<File_path>"; File source = new File(dirPath); and i'm planning to store the file object in array list. Does this sounds good? @simon5678

Comment: When I need to delete the file, I simply will remove the the deleted file from arrayList before moving to the second page. @kelvin

Comment: @sapthagiri-manivannan  Yes that's right.